Wall in kitchen near hallway wall with cabinet sandwiched between
We'd like to redo our kitchen, but we have this cabinet that pretty much goes to the ceiling that is sandwiched between the hallway wall and a wall that's built to the right side of the fridge. I keep wondering if it supports anything, but it makes no sense to me for it to be for support given that the hallway is to not far to the right and that's a support wall. My hope is to eliminate this wall and have regular cabinets and not lose space to this wall. Does anyone know what this might be?


Cabinets are not structural.  Now, if there's a wall behind the cabinet...  What's behind the cabinet?  Do you have better pics?

I'm having trouble getting a sense of the house layout from the angle of this fuzzy image. Please get a few better ones posted. Do you have access to the area below? Is there any plumbing or ductwork entering the wall?
